# How to display the publication date of a custom content item in its template

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I need to display a publication date in an alternate template.  I tried displaying the Model.Meta but it contains nothing.

I tried Model.Parts.Common.PublicationDate to no avail.  So how can I access the publication date?

```
<li>
    <a href="@displayUrl">
        <div style="padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;">
        @Display(Model.Meta) <!--contain nothing-->
        @Model.Parts.Common.PublicationDate; <!-- contain nothing -->
        <h2>@title</h2>

        @shortenedDescription
    </div>

    <div class="texthover">
        <div class="texthover-content">
            @if(Model.ContentItem.News.Image.Url != null){
                <img src="@Href(Model.ContentItem.News.Image.Url)" />
            }   
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the placement file in your theme, add the line:

```
<Match ContentType="MyType">
 <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="Meta:1" />
</Match>
```

Comment: This is it.  Thanks a lot!  Pandas now loves you more.

Comment: That is akin to winning life. And glad I could help!